# Select every other Document in Firestore Collection

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

I'm wondering how I can retrieve every other document in a Firestore collection. I have a collection of documents that include a date field. I'd like to sort them by date and then retrieve 1 document from every X sized block in the sorted collection. I'm adding a new document about every 10 seconds and I'm trying to display historical data on the front end without having to download so many records.

Comment: It depends how much data from the document that you want to display.  If you're trying to display time-series data for a graph, we do something similar by streaming new Cloud Firestore writes to Cloud Dataflow / Apache Beam (using Cloud Functions).

Comment: Have you checked out https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors ? 

Would it work for you to return not every other document but the next document 10 or more seconds away?
You can probably use some combination of limit(1) and startAfter() to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Sure can, just need to plan for it ahead of time.

## Random Sampling

Let's call this 'random sampling', so you'll need to determine your sample rate when you write the document. Let's assume you want to sample approximately 1 of every 10 documents (but not strictly 1 every 10).

When you write a document, add a field called `sample-10` and set it to `random(1,10)`. On query time add `.where("sample-10", "=", random(1,10))` to your query.

## Non-Random Sampling

This is harder when the source of your writes are distributed (e.g. many mobile devices), so I won't talk about it here.

If writes are coming from a single source, for example you might be graphing sensor data from a single source. This is easier in just incrementing the value put into `sample-10`  modulo 10.

## Other Sample Rates

You'll need to do a separate `sample-n` for different sample rates of `n`.